# How to reduce animate.css heartbeat enlarge size

Tags: css, animate.css

So I am using animate.css to animate a keyboard that shows what key to input. Currently I'm using *animate__heartbeat* to animate the keys to be pressed but the problem is the animation makes it overflow other keys and I would like to reduce that size.

[image]

These are the classes I am using on each keys:

> class="animate__animated animate__slow animate__infinite animate__heartBeat"

Since I am new to animate.css I dont know how to change the size it increases during the animation and is there a way to reduce it in css?

Comment: we cannot help if you dont share your codes

Comment: There is no code related to the keys its just div with classes and I only want to edit the heartbeat animation in the animate.css framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the **animate.min.css** go to this link https://unminify.com/ and unminify the css and find the below code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes heartBeat {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    14% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    28% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    42% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes heartBeat {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    14% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    28% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    42% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

and Replace them with:

```
@-webkit-keyframes heartBeat {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    14% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    28% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    42% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes heartBeat {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    14% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    28% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    42% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```